# Using backboneJS and loading two different builds of jquery works but not one or the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

This is a bit of a dated question but still curious and I am not pulling anything up, other than it is bad practice. (BTW the code that this is on will not be going to production with two)

I have a backbone.js app that I am updating jQuery from 1.9.1 to the 3.1.1. With how it is built up right now, I can use 3.1.1 but only if I also have version 2.2.4 loaded in as well. If I remove one or the other script tag, the app breaks and I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` and `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` as the errors that range across the board.
 I have added `var $= jQuery;` to where the jQuery is first loaded but that error still persists.

Wondering where I got off track and/or why this is happening.

**How the scripts are being loaded in**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/tooltip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/popper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/tooltip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/less.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/mobiledatepicker.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/serialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/sha256.min.js"></script>
```

Last thing I am on backbone 1.3.3 and bootstrap 4. The code does work up to jQuery version 2.0.3

Comment: `jQuery is not defined` indicates a plugin is trying to use `jQuery` before it is imported.

Comment: Right, I thought it was where it was imported in but I have moved it to the top of the scripts list and it is still throwing that error. jQuery is the first thing loaded in and double checked the network to confirm it is the first thing in.

Comment: you don't have the `async` attribute on the script include, do you?

Comment: You don't want the async attribute on any script include that is a dependency for another script include, so if you didn't have that, that's fine.  Not clear why it's saying its not defined then.  You said you checked your network console and you see that the request is being made, it's successfully pulling the file, and the resource pulled does indeed include the jQuery source code?

Comment: That is correct. It is showing both beings loaded, when it works, as well when it is only one.

Comment: What is extensions.js? What order are you loading your scripts? Can you post the code where you load these scripts so we can see what you're doing?

Comment: That was just one of the examples where that error was showing up. 

Edited it out for clarity

Comment: Aside from your current problem, I strongly recommend you use a taskrunner such as Webpack, Gulp, Grunt, to combine and minify your assets.

Comment: I have actually suggested that that issue was set on the backburner for a bit as most likely will the need to use a task runner to upgrade underscore

Comment: What happens when you comment out jQuery v2 (and backbone while you're at it) and type $ or jQuery in the console?

Comment: When I comment out one or the other, jQuery is undefined and `$` appears as undefined. As soon as I have both of them the console does log out info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So found out this was more to do with the window that I was loading it in. Don't and still can figure out why two version of jQuery would load and make the page responsive but a single one would not.

Issue came down to I was loading the pages and scripts into an electron app.

`<script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>` and
`<script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>` 
wrapped around the code cleared up the issue with only loading one.